# How to load sqlite3 console in ubuntu for rails 3.1.3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Our rails app runs on a ubuntu 10.04 server with sqlite3 database. How can we fire up sqlite3 console on the server? When typing sqlite3 ex1 under current/db/, there is error saying that sqlite3 not installed. However with "gem list", it shows sqlite3 1.3.5 installed.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQLite gem may be installed, but SQLite itself isn't

```
apt-get install sqlite3
```

Note: Not sure how Ubuntu handles this, but if `sqlite3` isn't a valid command, test also:

```
# Is any sqlite installed?
$ which sqlite

# If so, what version
$ sqlite --version
```

Comment: Nothing return for which sqlite. sqlite --version return error saying sqlite not installed. if sqlite gem is installed and functioning, why sqlite itself not?

Comment: @user938363 the sqlite client libs may be installed which allows Ruby to use it but the actual command line client isn't installed